# nginx alias using php5-fpm response 404

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, alias, http-status-code-404

I use php5 fpm using nginx. but i have a problem.

```
# debug alias
location /bb/ {
    alias /usr/share/blahblah/;
}
```

file on `http://mysite.localhost/bb/index.php` was not found. but it's still on `/usr/share/blahblah/index.php`

and this is an error:

```
*1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream
```

Comment: Have you checked file permissions? Have you checked the nginx/php-fpm error logs?

Comment: @Grumpy i'v check permission. it's right.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to load that file directly from disk, and instead proxy through fastcgi.  In that case, a rewrite of the url is probably more what you're looking for.

Comment: how can i figure it out. i think when i use alias document root for php fpm it isn't  valid.